# how to position partial view in asp.net mvc through java script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using partial view for my project but my problem is that my links are on right side of masterpage and when i clicked on particular link the view should displayed on left side on contentplace holder of master page. but right now its showing exactly below so my whole disgne is distrubed.

how to position partial view in asp.net mvc through java script?
 so please if anyone know the solution tell me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you basically mean your HTML is not set to allow the Content on the left, and the Menu on the right?

Maybe you would benefit from a [CSS Layout Template](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/)? Put the Content placeholder in large column, and the menu PartialView in the side bar.

Comment: still its not working. i done css carefully but still new page is getting displayed below the link. plz tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your page CSS. Look at your styles for "Float" 's. If you want your content to be to the left of your page, surround your contentPlaceHolder with a div tag and add a "float:left" style to it.

If that doesn't work it might be your view is wider than your master page design is set up for. So it will pop below every other page element to fit on your page!

Answer (score 0):

This is not realy asp.net mvc specific but html. You will have a better chance to solve your problem if you tag your question as html and css.

You can just save the source (I mean the rendered source from within the browser) of the page that doesnt display properly with the extension html in the root of your web. Then start playing with the html.

Request the page by calling http://yourserver/yourpagetodebug.html.

Comment: still its not working. i done css carefully but still new page is getting displayed below the link. plz tell me the solution